# URLDownloadToFile Function in a loop does not work as the function returns 0 even if there is no file to download

Tags: excel, download, vba

I was building myself a excel sheet to keep track of my investments. I have this link of the stock exchange website that has a single zip file containing a CSV file of the trading data of the last trading day. The name of the zipfile is dynamic in the form "eq_csv.zip where the ddmmyy is the date of the trading day for which the data pertains to. Therefore, the available file may be of the current day or 2-4 days old if the markets were closed.

I built a module to check online everytime I open my excel file to get the most current online data. The code given below was supposed to loop starting with the current date and move back by 1 day till I got the valid zip file downloaded. For eg, if the current date is Apr 28 (Sun) and if the file on the online resource is of Apr 26 (Fri) (eq260413_CSV.zip), then my loop should go through 3 iterations (2 no file msgs and one file downloaded msg) and download the file eq260413_CSV.zip. As the file eq280413_CSV.zip or eq290413_CSV.zip do not exist at the online link mentioned, I expect   to return an error and continue to loop. Whereas on running the code I find that the  function just creates a dummy file eq280413_CSV.zip with no data during the very first pass and returns a value of 0 to iRet whereby exiting the loop. Can ANyone please help / throw some light

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Worksheets("Online Equity Data").Activate

Dim StrURL As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim dDate As Date
Dim iRet As Long

dDate = Now() + 1
iRet = 1
vFolderName = "C:\Users\Deep\Documents\Finances\Test\"

Do While iRet <> 0
    dDate = dDate - 1
    StrURL = "http://www.bseindia.com/download/BhavCopy/Equity/eq" & Format(dDate, "ddmmyy") & "_csv.zip"
    strPath = vFolderName & "eq" & Format(dDate, "ddmmyy") & "_csv.zip"
    iRet = URLDownloadToFile(0, StrURL, strPath, 0, 0)
     If iRet= 0
        MsgBox "File eq" & Format(dDate, "ddmmyy") & "_csv.zip Downloaded"
    Else
        MsgBox "No File Named eq" & Format(dDate, "ddmmyy") & "_csv.zip"  
    End If
Loop

'More code Here to unzip and import the downloaded data

End Sub()
```

Comment: Crossposted at [SOCIAL.MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/3aa39a47-9989-43fd-bc53-9a95b620b4ab)

Comment: Sorry about the cross post.... I misunderstood the term to mean within one site.  I have also posted this initally at [excel forums] (http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/918793-using-error-handling-within-a-loop.html) one day of no solution from excel forums and not reaching anywhere with my own searches lead to my trying out differerent sites. The impatience and frustration of a newbie to the wonderland of VBA I guess. But lesson well learnt

Comment: In that case, I would recommend mentioning this link there as well. Else lot of experts of that site will waste their time trying to solve it. :) Thanks for being honest :)

Comment: I have already done that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `URLDownloadToFile` File API is not supposed to be used when the file/URL doesn't exists.

You have to first check if the URL is valid and then use `URLDownloadToFile` if applicable.

Use the below function written by Leith Ross (Picked up from [HERE](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/772794-pull-data-from-website-source.html))

```
'Written: March 15, 2011
'Author:  Leith Ross

Public PageSource As String
Public httpRequest As Object

Function GetURLStatus(ByVal URL As String, Optional AllowRedirects As Boolean)
    Const WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString = 0
    Const WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6

    On Error Resume Next
    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    If httpRequest Is Nothing Then
        Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString) = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
    httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = AllowRedirects

    'Clear any pervious web page source information
    PageSource = ""

    'Add protocol if missing
    If InStr(1, URL, "://") = 0 Then
        URL = "http://" & URL
    End If

    'Launch the HTTP httpRequest synchronously
    On Error Resume Next
    httpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      'Handle connection errors
        GetURLStatus = Err.Description
        Err.Clear
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Send the http httpRequest for server status
    On Error Resume Next
    httpRequest.Send
    httpRequest.WaitForResponse
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      ' Handle server errors
        PageSource = "Error"
        GetURLStatus = Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
      'Show HTTP response info
        GetURLStatus = httpRequest.Status & " - " & httpRequest.StatusText
      'Save the web page text
        PageSource = httpRequest.responsetext
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

When the URL is OK you will get something like this

[image]

And when it is not, you will get something like this

[image]

So all you need to do is look for `200 - OK` and if you get that, then use the `URLDownloadToFile` to download the file.

Comment: Thank You @Siddharth Rout... worked like a dream, used the Lieth Ross's Function and modified my code to the following.
` Do While iRet <> 200
        dDate = dDate - 1
        StrURL = "MyURL/eq" & Format(dDate, "ddmmyy") & "_csv.zip"
        iRet = Val(GetURLStatus(StrURL, False))
    Loop`